# What security measures does Chrome have in place to sandbox different user accounts?

Tags: web-browser, chrome

Google Chrome has a [feature](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en) that allows different users to use Chrome on the same computer in a completely separate space.

The support page is quite light on information. Is there information available about the security of this particular feature? What sort of measures are in place to prevent attacks against a particular user account from affecting another user account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a true sandbox. It is more a way to keep several "profiles" in a way similar to what Mozilla/Firefox have always done: basically, each such "user" will have his own set of cookies and browsing history, but, at the OS level, there is just one Chrome and one user account. The normal Chrome "sandboxing" is active in the following sense: code within one page shall not escape the browser and mess with the user's files (or, for that matter, with other pages or tabs). However, if malicious code does succeed in escaping that sandbox, then nothing will prevent it from altering the profiles of all "Chrome users" because the protection at that level is from the OS, and the OS is oblivious to this separation into multiple "Chrome users".

Chrome has long resisted adding such a feature, claiming that it was better to use several OS-level accounts. They were theoretically right, but it seems that market pressure trumps theory every time; and then they yielded.

Answer (score 0):

As the page states (in the yellow box) this are only different profiles. So in one user folder several profiles are generated. This users are not really isolated against each other.

To secure the users against each other you have to use different OS users.